# How to configure different batch sizes for different queues in "webjobs v3"?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, queuetrigger

There is some documentation on configuring different batch sizes for different queues using customQueueProcessor in webjobs v2 using .net framework. I would like to know how this is handled in webjobs v3?

```
       var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage(a =>
                {
                    a.BatchSize = 1;
                });
            })
```

This batch size is applicable for all the QueueTriggers in the code. How to use custom values for different queues?

Comment: Nothing has changed with the signature that I can see. Did you have an issue with using `a.BatchSize = 1;` when you upgraded v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set BatchSize per queue, you can implement an IQueueProcessorFactory:

```
public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context.Queue.Name.Equals("fooqueue"))
        {
            // demonstrates how batch processing behavior can be customized
            // per queue (as opposed to the global settings that apply to ALL queues)
            context.BatchSize = 3;
            context.NewBatchThreshold = 4;
            ...
        }

        return new QueueProcessor(context);
    }
}
```

In this case - all queues will use your default BatchSize configuration, but queue trigger "fooqueue" will have BatchSize set to 3.

Register CustomQueueProcessorFactory in your ConfigureServices method as so:

```
builder.ConfigureServices((services) =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessorFactory, CustomQueueProcessorFactory>();
});
```